# Funk transform of density supported on an embedded curve

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-geometry

A Funk transform is a certain invertible linear transformation on the space of square-integrable functions on $S^2$. I think its domain can be extended to include densities supported on embedded curves having finitely many intersections with any great circle. Is there some simple sufficient condition for a function on $S^2$ to be Funk transform of such a density?